# Go GORM db.Automigrate

Tags: go, variadic-functions, go-gorm

I use Go-GORM to connect to a cockrouch DB cluster. I wrote a helper function to handle the connection and auto migrate part. Everything works fine, except when I want to auto migrate more than 1 model.

```
err = helperdb.HandleMigrate(db, models.Resource{}, models.Right{})
if err != nil {
    helperlog.Log("Clavem", "HandleMigrate", "Error migrating resource:"+err.Error())
    return
}
```

This is the helper function:

```
// HandleMigrate ...
func HandleMigrate(db *gorm.DB, models ...interface{}) error {

// this need to be checked
err := db.AutoMigrate(models).Error
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error HandleMigrate:" + err.Error())
    return err
}

return nil
```

}

I get the following error:

```
pq: empty table name: "\"\""
```

When I call `gorm.DB.AutoMigrate(&models.Resurce{}, models.Right{})` directly I get no error.

I realise that I do not need a helper function, but I would like to know why the helper functions does not work, especially since it is my first time working my variadic functions.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure you just need to do:

```
err := db.AutoMigrate(models...).Error
```

Variadic functions receive the arguments as a slice of the type. In this case your function receives a  `[]interface{}` named `models`. When you pass that argument to `db.AutoMigrate`, you are passing it as a single argument of type `[]interface{}`.

What you really want is to pass each value in args as a separate argument (the same way you received them). To do this you must use the `...` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make this modification:

```
// HandleMigrate ...
func HandleMigrate(db *gorm.DB, models ...interface{}) error {

// this need to be checked
err := db.AutoMigrate(models...).Error
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error HandleMigrate:" + err.Error())
    return err
}

return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the models as a variadic arg to your automigrate call. Automigrate accepts multiple model parameters (as in `db.AutoMigrate(model1{}, model2{}, model3{})`), not an array.

I threw together an analog example printing strings in the playground here:
https://play.golang.org/p/qPTLqBvsen